# Primitive of a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I need some help with this exercise, about calculating the primitive of a distribution $T$ given by a series. Is the following:

$$<T,\phi>=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\phi(n)\;\;\;\;\phi\in\cal{D}(\mathbb{R})$$

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Do you know the primitive for $T(\phi)=\phi(1)$?

Comment: I think so...is it $-\chi_{(-\infty,1]}$? 

The reason:

$<T_{-\chi_{(-\infty,1]}}',\varphi>=-<T_{-\chi_{(-\infty,1]}},\varphi'>$

$=-\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\chi_{(-\infty,1]}\varphi'=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{1}\varphi'=\varphi(1)-\varphi(-\infty)=\varphi(1)$

Is this ok? How can this help to solve the question?
Thanks, Vobo.

Comment: Don't you get this? What is the derivative of $\phi(1)+\ldots+\phi(n)$?

Comment: I have this:

If we consider $f:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}-\chi_{(-\infty,k)}$, then:

$<T_{f}',\varphi>=-<T_{f},\varphi'>$

$=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\varphi'=\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}-\chi_{(-\infty,k)})\varphi'\underbrace{=}_{*}$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{(-\infty,k)}\varphi'=$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{k}\varphi'=$

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\varphi(k)$


With this I have $f$ is the primitive of the partial sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\varphi(k)$. But:

Comment: How can I extend this to the full series? Why is the step (*) legitimated when $n=\infty$?

Comment: In fact, $n$ is never $\infty$ ... This is the justification for your step (*).

Comment: Ahhh, I see. That's because $\phi$ has compact support, so we can find a $n_0$ that verifyes $\varphi(s)=0\;\forall s:|s|>n_0$. So the series is not a series in strict sense.

Thanks Vobo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finally answer the question: Let $H_n(x)$ be the Heaviside function with the step 1 at $x=n$, i.e. $H_n(x)=0$ for $x<n$ and $H_n(x)=1$ for $x\geq n$. As $H_n'=\delta_n$, you have for a test function $\varphi$
$$
(\sum_n H_n)'(\varphi)=-(\sum_n H_n)(\varphi') = (\sum_n H_n')(\varphi) = \sum_n \delta_n(\varphi) = \sum_n \varphi(n)
$$
as the considered sum is in fact *finite* due to the compact support of $\varphi$. So the general solution is
$$
\sum_n H_n + \text{const}.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot again, Vobo!!

Comment: But just one more doubt. Is my approach also correct? I say it because the functions we defined are not the same...

Comment: They are the same. $(H_n + const)'=\delta$ and your function differ from $H_n$ by a constant.